# add two horizontal lines between a figure and a table

Tags: floats, captions

I want to add two horizontal lines between each figure and each table but I have to add this command everytime : `\rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm}`

And how can I reduce the red space between the caption and the figure ? Is there a way to put the figure and table in the center without adding `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` ? If I can do that, I won't have the red space anymore I guess.

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,format=hang}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure-Example.}
\begin{center}
\rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{logo.png}
\rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm} 
\end{center}
\textit{Source :} \href{google.com}{https://google.com}
\end{figure}
%Table :
\begin{table}
\caption{Table-Example.}
\begin{center}
\rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
 A & B \\
 C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm}
\end{center}
\textit{Source :} \href{google.com}{https://google.com}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: Do not use the `center` environment  within a figure: it adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead.

Comment: But if i use `\centering` I will have my  `\textit{Source :} \href{google.com}{https://google.com}` at the center as well.

Comment: For that you can make a group. Captions are centred by default – how do you manage it?

Comment: Well i just tried something like this `\caption*{\textit{Source} : \href{google.com}{https://google.com}}` with `\centering` and it's not bad at all, so now I have to figure out how to add 2 lines without adding `\rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm}  ` everytime.

Comment: If I may, I think  the full width lines  for  tables  are somewhat redundant w.r.t. the `\hline`s of the table.

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation of the `float` package: it defines a `ruled` float style. You might define a `ruledfigure` and a `ruledtable` environments.

Answer (score 1):

With `\newenvironment{name}{begin}{end}`, it can be done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,format=hang}
\newenvironment{tablewithrule}[2]{\begin{table} \caption{#1} \centering \rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm} \caption*{\textit{Source}: #2}  }{\vspace{1mm}\rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm}  \end{table}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tablewithrule}{Table Example}{\url{www.google.com}}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
 A & B \\
 C & D \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tablewithrule}
\end{document}
```

However, it is not possible to have an argument in the end-part of the order. You've therefore to add it in the begin-part (if you want to have this automatic...).

The distance to the rules can be changed by `\vspace{}`, where you can also enter a negative value, e.g. `\vspace{-0.4cm}`

Edit: you could also work with `\renewenvironment` instead of `\newenvironment`. I however prefer not to meddle with the basic definitions but do new commands based on existing ones.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late answer. I tried it but it didn't work I don't get the lines between my figure/table when I add `\newenvironment{tablewithrule}[2]{\begin{table} \caption{#1} \centering \rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm} \caption*{\textit{Source}: #2}  }{\vspace{1mm}\rule[0.6ex]{\textwidth}{0.3mm}  \end{table}}`

Comment: Working fine with me. You've to change the `\begin{table}` to `\begin{tablewithrule}`, same with `\end{table}`. If you don't want that, you've to use `\renewenvironment`